# Implementing a Pipe in C++

Tags: c++, unix, input, pipe, output

I am having trouble implementing my pipe. It reads Unix terminal commands from a text file for commands such as "ls|wc" where it opens a pipe so that the output of ls can be used for wc.

I have implemented it to parse program names ("ls", "wc") and store them in two separate arrays (arguments and arguments2), fork a child process, then have that child fork another child process, then the second child process calls the execvp() command and passes the first program to be executed.

The output from ("ls") is then written to the pipe by changing the standard output. The former child process then execvp()'s the other process ("wc") and reads from the pipe by changing the standard input.

However, wc loops indefinitely and does not seem to count the number of words from ls. Ls executes in a directory where there are words to be counted.

Any tips? Thank you so much and sorry for the long explanation.

Here is a simpler example: It forks, creates a pipe, and implements "ls" and writes its output to the pipe, goes back to the parent and reads from the pipe the output of "ls". It still seems to be reading forever or not working right.

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  Pipe_Test
//
//  Created by Dillon Sheffield on 9/28/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Dillon Sheffield. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* arguments[2];
    char* programArguments[1];
    int fd[2];

    arguments[0] = new char[2];
    arguments[1] = new char[2];
    programArguments[0] = new char[1];
    programArguments[0][0] = '\0';
    string ls = "ls";
    string wc = "wc";
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        arguments[0] = &ls.at(i);
        arguments[1] = &wc.at(i);
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    pipe(fd);

    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("Failed.\n");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

        execvp(arguments[0], programArguments);
    }

    wait(NULL);

    dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    execvp(arguments[1], programArguments);

    close(0);
    close(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my original code:

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  homework2
//
//  Created by Dillon Sheffield on 9/19/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Dillon Sheffield. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

// Global Variable(s)
const short inputLineSize = 10; // Size of programName, arguments, and argument name.
char *arguments[inputLineSize];
char *arguments2[inputLineSize];
ifstream inputFile;
char* input;

void readLine()
{
    // Create new char array(s)
    input = new char[inputLineSize];

    // Initialize the char array(s)
    for (int i = 0; i < inputLineSize; i++)
    {
        input[i] = '\0';
    }

    // Read a line and skip tabs, spaces, and new line characters
    for (int i = 0; !inputFile.eof() && inputFile.peek() != '\n'; i++)
    {
        while (inputFile.peek() == '\n' || inputFile.peek() == '\t' || inputFile.peek() == ' ') inputFile.get();
        inputFile.get(input[i]);
    }

    // If the file is multi-spaced, keep reading new line char(s) to clear them
    while (inputFile.peek() == '\n') inputFile.get();
}

void parseTokens()
{
    //----------Parse the read line into tokens--------------------------------------------//

    // Get the program name
    for (int i = 0; i < inputLineSize; i++)
    {
        arguments[i] = new char[inputLineSize];
        for (int j = 0; j < inputLineSize; j++)
            arguments[i][j] = '\0';
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (input[i] != '\0' && input[i] != '-' && input[i] != '|')
    {
        arguments[j][i] = input[i];
        i++;
    }

    // Tokenize arguments if supplied
    j++;
    int k;
    while (input[i] == '-')
    {
        k = 0;
        arguments[j][k] = input[i];
        i++;
        k++;

        while (input[i] != '-' && input[i] != '\0')
        {
            arguments[j][k] = input[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        j++;
    }

    // Delete unused arguments
    while (j < inputLineSize)
    {
        delete arguments[j];
        arguments[j] = NULL;
        j++;
    }

    // Check if the pipe command '|' is supplied
    if (input[i] == '|')
    {
        i++;

        // Get the other program name
        for (int x = 0; x < inputLineSize; x++)
        {
            arguments2[x] = new char[inputLineSize];
            for (int y = 0; y < inputLineSize; y++)
                arguments2[x][y] = '\0';
        }

        int x = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (input[i] != '\0' && input[i] != '-' && input[i] != '|')
        {
            arguments2[j][x] = input[i];
            i++;
            x++;
        }

        // Tokenize arguments if supplied
        j++;
        int k;
        while (input[i] == '-')
        {
            k = 0;
            arguments2[j][k] = input[i];
            i++;
            k++;

            while (input[i] != '-' && input[i] != '\0')
            {
                arguments2[j][k] = input[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
            j++;
        }

        // Delete unused arguments
        while (j < inputLineSize)
        {
            delete arguments2[j];
            arguments2[j] = NULL;
            j++;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Variable(s)
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t pid2;
    int fd[2];

//--Open the file named "input"-------------------------------------------------------//

    inputFile.open("input", ios::in);

    // Check if opening the file was successful
    if (inputFile.is_open())
    {
        // Read until the file has reached the end
        while (!inputFile.eof())
        {
            // Read a line and parse tokens
            readLine();
            parseTokens();

//----------Now create a new process with parsed Program Name and Arguments-----------//

            // Create a pipe
            pipe(fd);

            // Fork
            pid = fork();
            if (pid < 0)
            {
                perror("Fork failed.\n");
                return -2;
            }
            else if (pid == 0)
            {
                // Fork again
                pid2 = fork();

                if (pid2 < 0)
                {
                    perror("Fork failed.\n");
                    return -2;
                }
                else if (pid2 == 0)
                {
                    // Change standard output
                    if (dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO) != STDOUT_FILENO) perror("dup2 error to stdout.\n");

                    // Execute the given program
                    execvp(arguments[0], arguments);
                }


                // Change the standard input to the pipe
                if (dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO) != STDIN_FILENO) perror("dup2 error to stdin.\n");

                int returnValue = execvp(arguments2[0], arguments2);
                if (returnValue == -1) perror("Error has occurred.\n");

                // Close the pipe and exit
                close(fd[0]);
                close(fd[1]);
                exit(0);
            }

            // Wait for the child so it doesn't become a Zombie
            wait(NULL);


//----------Clean up-----------------------------------------------------------------//
            delete input;
            input = NULL;
            int i = 0;
            while (arguments[i] != NULL)
            {
                delete arguments[i];
                arguments[i] = NULL;
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    else perror("Cannot open file.\n");

    inputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be attempting two tricky things at once: reading/parsing unix commands, and executing them with forks and pipes. *Separate* these two things, and test them in isolation; at the least this will get you closer to a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You first execute a `pipe()`, then you execute a `fork()`, and the child process, with some additional work, executes your commands.

The problem here is that the `pipe()`d file descriptors, both of them, remain open in the original parent process. Both the read-side of the pipe, and, more importantly, the write-side of the pipe. These file descriptors do, from all appearances, get correctly set up for your child processes, but because the file descriptors also remain open in the parent process, the pipe never closes, even after the process that writes to the write side of the pipe terminates.

Since the write side of the pipe remains open, in the parent process, the child process that's reading the read side of the pipe will continue reading. Forever.

What you need to do is that after the fork, in the parent process, close both the read and the write side of the pipe. Once the initial process gets forked, the parent process does not need the pipe, and its open file descriptors get in the way.

Comment: Thank you, Sam. I cannot seem to get it to work still. Where should I add the close(fd[0]) and close(fd[1]) commands exactly? I guess I'm a bit confused on that.

Comment: In the parent process, as I explained.

Comment: My code does close the ends of the pipes in the parent process though?

Comment: No, it clearly closes them in the first forked child process. It doesn't close them in the original, parent process.

Comment: Okay, I closed them in the parent process right after the fork but it still seems to be reading endlessly...

Comment: Your code for the child processes dups() one of the file descriptors to the child process's stdin or stdout. However, it also doesn't close the original file descriptor. So, the child process that reads from the pipe on stdin will also have the original file descriptors open as well. After dup-ing each file descriptor, in both of the child processes, you also need to close them there too.